# Update Quantity Available using Quantity from another table

Tags: mysql, update, subquery

> 1. You will demonstrate an update that includes two tables and uses a subquery.
>
>    Make sure to prove that your update executed correctly by showing data in the tables before and after the update.

I'd like to update the quantity available based on `quantity ordered - table book Available = Available - quantity` from orders table

This is what I have so far: BUT IT's not Working

```
SELECT Available 
FROM   book 
WHERE  Available IN (SELECT ALL(Available) 
                     FROM   orders 
                     WHERE  Quantity >= 1);

UPDATE book 
SET book.Available = Available - (SELECT orders.quantity 
                                  FROM orders 
                                  WHERE orders.ISBN_No=book.ISBN_No) 
WHERE Available IN (SELECT ALL(Available) 
                    FROM orders 
                    WHERE Quantity >= 1);

SELECT Available
FROM book
WHERE Available IN (SELECT ALL(Available) 
                    FROM orders 
                    WHERE Quantity >= 1);
```

Here are the 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE book
(
ISBN_No INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Title VARCHAR(30),
Author VARCHAR(50),
Publisher VARCHAR(50),
Publication_Date DATE,
Genre VARCHAR(25),
Condition_type VARCHAR(5),
Cost DECIMAL(8,2),
Available INT(5)
);

INSERT INTO book VALUES
(0234567890, 'Harry Potter Collection', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Bloomsbury', '2010-01-01', 'Children', 'NEW', '65.00', 7),
(0987654321, 'Lord of the Rings Collection', 'J.R.R. Tolkein', 'Harper', '2001-02-15', 'Fantasy', 'USEDA', '18.00', 1),
(0421548752, 'The Help', 'Kathryn Stockett', 'Del Rey', '2015-03-25', 'Fiction', 'USEDG', '9.00', 3),
(0545454235, 'Pride and Prejudice', 'Jane Austin', 'Scholastic', '1999-12-05', 'Classic', 'USEDG', '12.00', 2),
(0458742154, 'Alexander Hamilton', 'Ron Chernow', 'Scholastic', '2017-06-12', 'Biography', 'NEW', '24.00', 12);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
Order_No INT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
Order_date DATE,
ISBN_No INT(10) NOT NULL,
Quantity INT(5),
Cost DECIMAL(8,2),
Total DECIMAL(8,2),
Delivery_Method VARCHAR(6),
Payment_type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
Credit_Card VARCHAR(16),
Credit_Exp DATE,
Employee_ID INT(3),
Customer_No INT(11) NOT NULL,  

FOREIGN KEY (Customer_No)
REFERENCES customer(Customer_No),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID)
REFERENCES employee(Employee_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ISBN_No) 
REFERENCES book(ISBN_No)
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES 
(101112, '2018/01/29', 0234567890, '2', 65.00, 130.00, 'UPS', 'D', '54661625258778596', '2020/01/22', 004, 100100),
(101100, '2018/01/18', 0421548752, '1', 9.00, 9.00, 'UPS', 'CC', '8546587785965222', '2020/12/22', 004, 100100),
(101106, '2018/01/23', 0545454235, '1', 12.00, 12.00, 'USPS', 'CASH', 'NULL', 'NULL', 004, 784521),
(101109, '2018/01/25', 0458742154, '5', 24.00, 120.00, 'USPS', 'CC', '6541254265874856', '2025/02/22', 005, 784521),
(101105, '2018/01/27', 0545454235, '1', 12.00, 12.00, 'USPS E', 'CASH', 'NULL', 'NULL', 004, 784521);
```

I'm stuck.  What I have above I've tried changing in so many different ways to no avail.

Comment: Use the multi-table syntax, not `IN ( SELECT ... )`